# Payments with Django, outside US

Tags: django, payment-gateway

I have developed a web application in Django that accepts payments (and recurring payments) in paypal. Application works OK, however users encourage me to consider other payment options.

Problem is that I tried some and either (a) did not find an API to work on, or (b) do not offer their services outside the US (e.g. stripe or BrainTree[*]).

So my question is, do you know of a payment method that would integrate with django as easy as django-paypal and work for companies outside the US?

Chris

[*] Although BT does not offer services outside the US, I have been given the option to contact them about that. I contacted them and I am waiting for their answer.

Comment: you have to try [http://www.planetpayment.com/](http://www.planetpayment.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [Ogone](http://www.ogone.com/). I found a project that integrates this with Django [here](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-ogone).